# FragmentTabHost FragmentManager is invalid

Tags: android, xamarin, fragment-tab-host

I'm developing an app using xamarin.android in visual studio, and i'm trying to add Tabs on the buttom of my app
And this is my code

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);                      

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);


        FragmentTabHost fragmentTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)FindViewById(Resource.Id.tabhost);
        fragmentTabHost.Setup(this, FragmentManager, Resource.Id.tabcontent);
    }
```

Then i get this error

> cannot convert from 'Android.App.FragmentManager' to 'Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager'

And when i change this

```
fragmentTabHost.Setup(this, FragmentManager, Resource.Id.tabcontent);
```

To this

```
fragmentTabHost.Setup(this, Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager, Resource.Id.tabcontent);
```

I get this error instead

> 'FragmentManager' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

I've been stuck on this for a while, any help is appreciated

EDIT :
When i try to add a tab with this code

```
fragmentTabHost.AddTab(fragmentTabHost.NewTabSpec("fragmenta").SetIndicator("Fragment A"), new SubsFragment(), null);
```

I get this error

> cannot convert fragment to java.Lang.class

Any advice is wellcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
fragmentTabHost.Setup(this, FragmentManager, Resource.Id.tabcontent);
```

to

```
fragmentTabHost.Setup(this, this.SupportingFragmentManager, Resource.Id.tabcontent);
```

The compiler is expecting the support version of FragmentManager and you need to specify it as such. Just putting `Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager` doesn't work because that's a name of a class and it's expecting an instantiated object of *type* `Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager`.

Another important thing, if you look at the code `this.SupportingFragmentManager`, you'll notice the keyword `this` being used. If you're calling `this.SupportingFragmentManager` from a `FragmentActivity` the code will work as is, otherwise get a reference to your FragmentActivity and call `SupportingFragmentManager` on it. Like so:

`fragmentTabHost.Setup(this, myFragmentActivity.SupportingFragmentManager, Resource.Id.tabcontent);`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer, Would you take a look at the updated post